# Factorial calculation is not right in my C program?

Tags: c, factorial

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
  long signed fact=1;

  int c, n ;

  printf("Factorial to be calculated: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  for (c = 1; c <= n; c++)
  fact = fact * c;

  printf("Factorial of %d = %ld\n", n, fact);
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

In the C program above, when I run, I can not get 13! correct. It's output is true for 12. How can I fix this?
I thought long unsigned will be enough for 13.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible that `long` is 32-bit on your platform (you can find out by printing the value of `sizeof(long)`).  13! is greater than 2^32-1 (the largest possible value for a 32-bit unsigned value), so it overflows.

Try using `uint64_t` (from `<stdint.h>`) instead.

Answer (score 3):

What Oli said is correct -- the C standard guarantees that `long` is at least 32 bits. On some platforms it might be more.

You could use `unsigned long long`. This would be at least 64 bits, but it would still only let you calculate up to 20!.

The C FAQ has an excellent overview on integer sizes: [How should I decide which integer type to use?](http://c-faq.com/decl/inttypes.html) You'll probably want to look for an arbitrary-precision library.

Otherwise, if you only want to approximate larger factorials, perhaps you could use [Stirling's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).